# Granger Causality lag / Impulse Response

Tags: time-series, vector-autoregression, granger-causality

I have a question regarding the connection between Granger Causality Analysis and a VAR Impulse Response Function.

Let's say we intend to conduct a Granger causality analysis and first make sure that the VAR model is well specified. In the end, we find that lag = 2 is the best fit according to AIC and BIC. We subsequently test for Granger causality (Wald-test) and indeed we find a causality ( $X \rightarrow Y$ 0.04** vs $Y\rightarrow X$ 0.56).

However, if we apply the Impulse Response Function (IRF) of the VAR, we see that the most significant shock seems to be at lag = 4.

Is this possible that we find Granger Causality for lag = 2 but the most significant (cumulative) IRF for lag = 4? Or is there a conflicting result?

Comment: Interesting question. I do not have a good answer, but perhaps the devil is in details. Lag length selection by AIC (or BIC) is typically done by obtaining AIC for unrestricted models with lags up to $p$ for $p$ between 1 (or 0) and some $p_{max}$, and finding the lowest one. Suppose the true model is best approximated by a VAR(4) model with coefficient matrices for the first three lags rather close to zero but the fourth lag having substantial effect size. It could happen that AIC would select VAR(2) because a VAR(4) with the first the lags having zero coefs is not among the alternatives.

Comment: Also, when it comes to Granger causality we think in terms of VAR representation of the process but when considering IRF we think in terms of VMA representation. Could the paradox have roots here? Also, although you have explained your problem clearly, it would nevertheless be interesting to see the estimated VAR (coefficients and all the standard output) and the IRF graphs.